# Who created indexes?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possibile to check who created indexes on SQL Server? I found only script which list time:

```
select STATS_DATE(so.object_id, index_id) StatsDate
, si.name IndexName
, schema_name(so.schema_id) + N'.' + so.Name TableName
, so.object_id, si.index_id
from sys.indexes si
inner join sys.tables so on so.object_id = si.object_id
order by StatsDate desc
```

Comment: I created [dbhistory.com](http://dbhistory.com) exactly for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. But if that's important for you to know for indexes created going forward, you can set up an event notification session or ddl trigger to track that information.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not here for the fake internet points, but if my answer is in some way incorrect, be constructive (by either commenting or providing your own answer).

Answer (score 1):

For recent indexes you can use Schema Change History report it is available by default ([check this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/07/sql-server-ssms-schema-change-history-report/)).  Login name is tracked.

Also there are multiple options to use schema changes tracking ([check this blog series](https://blog.sqlterritory.com/2019/01/01/7-ways-to-track-database-schema-changes-part-6-event-notifications/))